# returning data from a stack Java

Tags: java, stack, comparison, parentheses

I am trying to balance parentheses. I was getting an error "cannot compare objects with primitives" when I tried to do something like stack.peek() == '{'    I casted it to character. The compiler takes it, but warns about unsafe operations. Does anyone know a better way I can do this and why I can push and pop characters from the stack as primitives, but it's not primitive when I peek?

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(String S) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

    char[] C = S.toCharArray();
    LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();

    for(int i = 0; i< C.length; i++){
        if(C[i] == '(' || C[i] == '[' || C[i] == '{'){
            stack.push(C[i]);   
        }

        if(C[i] == ')' && (char)stack.peek() == '('){
            stack.pop();   
        }
        else if (C[i] == ']' && (char)stack.peek() == '['){
            stack.pop();   
        }
        else if (C[i] == '}' && (char)stack.peek() == '{'){
            stack.pop();   
        }
    }

    if(stack.size() == 0){
        return 1;   
    }
    else{
        return 0;   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're seeing auto-boxing.  You should use generic collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the raw form of `LinkedList`, which will store `Object`s.  You can't cast an `Object` to a `char`.

Use a generic `LinkedList<Character>`.  Then `peek()` will return `Character`s, and Java will unbox them  to `char`s when comparing them with `==`.

```
LinkedList<Character> stack = new LinkedList<Character>();
```

Then you will find that you don't even need to cast the return of `peek()` to `char`.

Comment: just curious, would it work if I used the raw linked list and used .equals('}') to compare the object to the character or does .equals() only work between two objects? I still don't really get the point of parameterized types.

Comment: If you used `stack.peek().equals('}')`, then that should work, because the `char` would be boxed to a `Character`.  However, that wouldn't work with the other comparisons such as `C[i] == '('`, because you can't call methods such as `equals` on primitive types such as `char`.  Generic parameterized types means enhanced type safety.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have had this problem if you had used correctly the `LinkedList<T>` raw-type. Declare your list as `LinkedList<Character>` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice article -- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1932926&seqNum=5
It talks about the casts that are allowed and not allowed, for instance it says

> One thing you can’t do under any circumstance is cast from an object to a primitive   data type, or vice versa.Primitive types and objects are very different things in Java, and you can’t automatically cast between the two."

Just for future reference just in case Linked List can't be set to a particular type (because it could happen in certain circumstances) Code just needs to do a .equals except == for stack.peek() is an object and objects need .equals for comparison. Also the casting was just taken out.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.println(solution("{"));



}

public static int solution(String s) {
  char[] C = s.toCharArray();
LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();
System.out.println("Length:" + C.length);
for(int i = 0; i< C.length; i++){
    if(C[i] == '(' || C[i] == '[' || C[i] == '{'){

        stack.push(C[i]);   
    }
    System.out.println("Peek" + (C[i] == '}'));
    if(C[i] == ')' && stack.peek().equals('(')){
        stack.pop();   
    }
    else if (C[i] == ']' && stack.peek().equals('[')){
        stack.pop();   
    }
    else if (C[i] =='}' && stack.peek().equals('{')){
        System.out.println("POPPED");
        stack.pop();   
    }
}

if(stack.size() == 0){
    return 1;   
}
else{
    return 0;   
}
}
```

But the better way will be LinkedList of type Character

And no casting is not needed for neither solutions